# checklist pre-release

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0

I have developed a asp.net page and I'm ready to release it for the public. This is my first asp.net page and I would appreciate if I could get some tips of what to do pre-release. So I hope you all can help me put together a checklist before publishing.

Thanks
M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Choose a well voted, trustful hosting.
- Check overall security of your site, be sure you have nothing in Debug state. Also take a look at a [recently discovered security issue on .NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/18/important-asp-net-security-vulnerability.aspx)
- Don't forget logs. They are a key to check how things are going on once the app is released.
- Ask some relatives/friends to take a look from their point of view. Test as much as you can, remember that if you have 99% finished, there is another 99% yet to be finished :)
- Check your configuration files, and every setting on IIS once released.
- Be prepared (if not before) to apply SEO techniques in order to let your work be seen on most search engines.
- Test your site from many browsers (even the special ones as IE6 and Safari)
- Take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854084/production-release-checklist). here in StackOverflow.

Now, just cross your fingers and go on!

Hope that helps,